# «Да» и «нет» могут быть общими элементами?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп

*Да, мне трудно работать над этим проектом и задачи кажутся невыполнимыми, но я справлюсь.*

Слова «да» и «нет» позволяют не ставить запятую в ССП, являясь общими обособленными частицами?

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что речь здесь идет не об обособленной частице, а о **слове-предложении** — "да".

Такое предложение состоит из одного слова и выражает эмоциональную или волевую реакцию говорящего на ситуацию (в нашем случае это утверждение).
Слова-предложения представляют собой особый структурный тип и не могут быть отнесены ни к двусоставным предложениям, ни к односоставным.

Мне кажется, что слово **да** относится к обеим частям предложения, является для них общим, поэтому запятая перед **и** не нужна.
(Сравните: *Да, мне трудно работать над этим проектом. Да, задачи кажутся невыполнимыми. Но я справлюсь.* — Вторая часть предложения из первой не вытекает.)

**Да, мне трудно работать над этим проектом и задачи кажутся невыполнимыми, но я справлюсь.**

[Слова-предложения](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/280-slova-predlogeniya.html)

Comment: Слова-предложения являются отдельными предложениями, выражают самостоятельный смысл и, как правило, являются ответом на предыдущую реплику. В нашем случае «да» не имеет такого значения. Ещё один момент: если «да» — слово-предложение, как оно может относиться к двум последующим частям предложения, соединяясь с ними запятой? Запятая же обозначает перечисление.

Comment: Так ведь я и пишу, что НЕ НАДО запятой. (_Мне кажется, что слово да относится к обеим частям предложения, является для них общим, поэтому запятая перед и не нужна._) В этом предложении, возможно, "да" и не является ответом на предыдущее высказывание. Но что же это меняет в пунктуации? Думаю, ничего.

Comment: Вы неверно меня поняли. *Если «да» — слово-предложение, как оно может относиться к двум последующим частям предложения, соединяясь с ними запятой?* — «да» соединяется запятой с двумя последующими предложениями, а не те друг с другом.

Answer (score 2):

***Да***, мне трудно работать над этим проектом и задачи кажутся невыполнимыми, но я справлюсь.

Для проверки утвердительное слово ДА можно заменить **вводным словом** примерно с тем же утвердительным значением, а вводные слова относятся **к общим элементам**:

***Действительно***, мне трудно работать над этим проектом и задачи кажутся невыполнимыми, но я справлюсь.

ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО. I. нареч. В действительности, подлинно, в самом деле. Он д. очень устал. II. **вводн. сл. Подтверждает чью-л. мысль,** выражает уверенность в чём-л. На этот раз, д., он прав. III. **частица. Употр. для выражения утверждения**; да, верно. Он так сказал? - Д.

Answer (score 0):

Если не поставить запятую после "да", то это будет уже не подтверждение. "Да мне трудно работать..." подобно: "да не хочу я", "да что вы в самом деле", "да иди ты". После "нет" запятая так и так напрашивается.

Comment: Речь идет об отсутствии  запятой перед союзом И  при наличии общего слова ДА, отнесенного к обоим предложениям

Comment: В вопросе про "и" ни-ни.

Comment: Вопрос: _Слова «да» и «нет» позволяют не ставить запятую в ССП..._  Пояснение: 1. Сложносочинённые предложения (ССП) – это сложные предложения, в которых простые предложения связываются друг с другом интонацией и сочинительными союзами. 2. **И** в предложении – это сочинительный союз. 3. Надо ли ставить запятую перед "и"? Это и есть, собственно, вопрос.